# how to connect grails with mysql and why grails compile shows :compileJava NO-SOURCE

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, grails

I am facing problem using MySql with Grails 3 project.
Application.yml file--

```
---
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: false
        use_query_cache: false
dataSource: # <- CHANGE !!!
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

environments:
    development:
        dataSource: # <- CHANGE !!!
            username : root
            password :
            dbCreate : create-drop # one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url : jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/nsl_api
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none
            url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

in Build.gradle, I use `runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'`  dependencies.
When in use `grials compile` command I am getting `:compileJava NO-SOURCE`. how to add java source in itellij? I donot know it as I am new here. Please help.
Another error I am getting is

```
 ERROR --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

And another error is  `Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.`
How can I connect mysql database with my grails project? I also run xammp software where apache, mysql and tomcat is running. what should I do? How can I send data into mysql database and retrieve that data in a web page row by row.

Comment: Could you please describe your project structure?

Comment: I created this grails project using ` grails create-app books` command

Comment: Is your MySQL server from XAMMP running on port 8888 as described in line `url : jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/nsl_api` and do you have a db called `nsl_api`? Usually default port for MySQL is 3306, so if you are not sure then change it to `url : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nsl_api`. Also check out if you can log into MySQL as root without any password.

Comment: I check it again it's okay but same error happened again. I also faced (java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost) this error message

Comment: Please try to run "grails compile" from command line outside IDE. Will it show the same error?